# Is std::is_signed<bool>::value guaranteed to return false?

Tags: c++, boolean, signed

I know that [`std::numeric_limits<bool>::is_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_signed) will always be false but is that also true for [`std::is_signed<bool>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed)? Thanks

Comment: By those docs, clearly.  Looking for a standards quote?

Comment: Interesting question. `bool` is an integral type, therefore an arithmetic type, and `is_signed` is based on the check `is_arithmetic<T>::value && T(-1) < T(0)`

Comment: @Yakk yes, whatever support you can provide. If it isn't guaranteed in `std::is_signed<bool>::value` is there any disadvantage to testing for `std::numeric_limits<bool>::is_signed` instead in my templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::is_signed` is defined as follows (Table 49 - Type property predicates, n3485):

```
is_arithmetic<T>::value && T(-1) < T(0)
```

`bool` is an integral type [basic.fundamental]/7, therefore an arithmetic type [basic.fundamental]/8.

`bool(x)` where `x` is an `int`, uses the boolean conversion [conv.bool]/1

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. [...]

So we have `bool(-1) < bool(0)` evaluating to `true < false`, which is subject (see [expr.rel]/2) to the usual arithmetic conversions [expr]/10 => integral promotion [conv.prom]/6

> A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true`
>   becoming one.

The comparison then reads `1 < 0`, which is `false`. The the check is guaranteed to evaluate to `false`.

---

In n3797, after fixing [LWG 2197](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2197), the check is defined as follows:

> If `is_arithmetic<T>::value` is `true`, the same result as `integral_constant<bool, T(-1) < T(0)>::value`; otherwise, `false`

Which has the same result in case of `T == bool`.

Answer (score 1):

From 20.9.4.3, Table 49:

> is_arithmetic::value && T(-1) < T(0)

So what translates -1 to when converted into a bool? Naturally, 1:

> A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is
>   converted to false; any other value is converted to true.

(4.12)

Comment: And dyp correctly added the conversion to int I took for granted :-).